How to use free space on second drive in Ubuntu?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with two hard drives as follows:

/dev/sda :


/dev/sdb :



How can I use the free space on the second drive, /dev/sdb, for Ubuntu?

The free or unallocated space on your sdb device is far less than 1GB; what were you hoping to fit in less than 1GB of space?

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you have another drive for backup of both Windows & Ubuntu? Backup is vital unless you have no data you want to keep. Best to use Linux format like ext4 for Linux data. Windows NTFS does not support ownership & permissions. You can share data on NTFS if just data and Windows fast startup/hibernation is off. I prefer to label partitions so mounted by label if used occasionally, so I know which it is. UUID do not help  me  know which partition is which. Or mount with fstab if used regularly.

Terse answer; for preparation and occasional use:

lsblk -ape7 will tell about present hardware partitions.
The TYPE column says part for partitions.
Format the selected partition with a filesystem that suits your needs.
mount the partition,  e.g. udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/$device$part
cd <mountpoint>  # /media/$USER/<disk_label> for the above
sudo chown $USER:$USER . # likely required to allow access
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/$device$part # when done using

Note that 2. and 5. is required only once.
On boot / permanent mount not covered by this, look for /etc/fstab info.
mount/unmount can also be done from Nautilus (gnome Files) as well as from the command line, udisksctl uses the same "interface".
Note that a partition which is used from more than one OS has to be properly and fully flushed and unmounted before the next OS can use it. i.e. a hibernated or 'fastboot'-enabled Windows may cause trouble.
